# PDF 404 error with custom webroot in ISPConfig

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ispconfig

I have custom webroot in ISPConfig configured

Code:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/clients/client1/web18/web/web/"
<Directory {DOCROOT}>
Options -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

In that root directory I have directory "manual" `/var/www/site.tld/web/web/manual/` but I can't access any files in there, there are PDFs which are giving me 404 error when I am trying to access them via browser on url like `http://site.tld/manual/file.PDF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that, apache has their default manual page in alias like this.

```
Alias /manual /usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/

<Directory "/usr/share/doc/apache2-doc/manual/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    AddDefaultCharset off
</Directory>
```

I had to comment first line with "alias"